# Can't mount /system as read/write, even though I'm rooted

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mount

My phone is rooted, and I tried to remount the system partition in a terminal emulator like so:

```
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

Both commands gave the output:

```
mount : read-only file system
```

Because of that I can't install Busybox, Xposed, etc. I'm using Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently under the new AOS, in non-root you may have certain things mounted in one way, but when doing `su` you get it mounted (or not at all) in a diffrent way. This is proably due to the new SELinux protection schemes. For example, to resolve unmonted SDCards you have to do `su -mm`, when using SuperSU. In addition the `toolbox` supported `mount` command is a bit crappy at times, so you're better using busybox. Make sure you use the latest *SuperSU* as it is the only reliable way to get proper root credential under the new SELinux systems. Then try each of the following:

```
su -cn u:object_r:kernel:s0 -c "busybox mount -o rw,remount /system"
su -cn u:object_r:init_shell:s0 -c "busybox mount -o rw,remount /system"
su 0 -c "busybox mount -o rw,remount /system"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Gah, those commands all ran with no errors but I still can't write to /system/etc. Oddly I can create empty (0 byte) files and delete files but I cannot add a non-zero byte file. Something to do with inodes v.s. <whatever file system Android now uses> perhaps.