# Unable to mount /system as read-write

Tags: root-access, 5.1-lollipop, mount, xiaomi

I want to modify a file under /system. The problem is that is read-only, and even with root I cannot set it as read-write.

I've tried the following:

- Root Explorer (the automatic button)
- A one click app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.superthomaslab.mountsystemrorw)
- The following commands, on Terminal Emulator: `su` and after that `mount -o rw,remount /system`. Along with that some variants (specifiying `-t`, using `-rw`, `mount -o rw,remount /system /system`)

---

Some useful informations:

- The device is a Redmi 3
- Using android 5.1.1, on MIUI 6.4.7 (china developer version)
- I have root access, and enabled it for the apps mentioned above
- Bootloader is unlocked
- No SD card
- Output of `mount | grep system`: `/dev/block/dm-0 /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0`

---

I would like to manage the /system folder directly from the phone. I'm pretty hopeless, I've tried googling 2 hours for a working solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely a security thing with the device ([mount namespace separation](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/136101/16575)?). Also see: [Can't mount /system as read/write, even though I'm rooted](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/84066/16575) / [/system cannot be remounted as RW, even when rooted (Sony Xperia E3)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/126201/16575)

Comment: The first one is for Android 4, I would like to have a confirmation before executing those commands. I've already tried the other solution.

Comment: Understood. As I've never been in that situation, I must pass on that part to someone else (and cannot help further). Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the source of the problem asking in the MIUI forums, the boot image will not accept a modified /system.

You have to use the adb interface: `adb devices` then `adb disable-verity`.

Disclaimer: I'm not responsible for any damage caused by these operations.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works on USERDEBUG builds. Still looking for what works for stock builds.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user aalaap [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/136101/96277), disabling **Mount Namespace Separation** setting in **SuperSU** solved this issue for me on ZP999 and SuperSU 2.82 SR5.